# Adding AD group/user to a local group on MacOS Catalina using Core Services

Tags: c++, macos, core-services

I'm trying to add a AD user or group to my local group using OSX Core services and Objective-C
Currently this code gives me error code -2 which I guess is `kCSIdentityAuthorityNotAccessibleErr`. I couldn't find any good examples on how to do that so any help is welcome.

````
RetCode NixUtils::AddGroupMember(const std::string& sGroupName, const std::string& sMemberName)
{
    RetCode retCode = ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED;
    
    CSIdentityRef userRef = NULL;
    CSIdentityRef groupRef = NULL;
    AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;

    retCode = GetLocalIdentity(sGroupName, NULL, groupRef); //getting local group 
    if(retCode)
    {
            retCode = GetNetworkIdentity(sMemberName, NULL, userRef); //getting AD user
            if(retCode)
            {

                CSIdentityAddMember(groupRef, userRef);
                //not quite sure I'm using the right Authorization initialization for this operation      
                OSStatus status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, NULL, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &auth);
                   
                if(status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
                {
                    retCode = ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED;
                }
                else{
                    CFErrorRef errorRef;
                    bool success = CSIdentityCommit(groupRef, auth, &errorRef);
                    if(!success)
                    {
                        retCode = ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED;

                        CFIndex errCode = CFErrorGetCode(errorRef);

                        if(errorRef)
                        {
                            EMgr::ReportDebugTrace("NixUtils::AddGroupMember() error code %d! ", (long)errCode); // error code -2
                        } 
                    }
                    else{
                        EMgr::ReportDebugTrace("NixUtils::AddGroupMember() Commit Success!");
                    }
                }

            }
    }

    if(auth) CFRelease(auth);
    if(userRef) CFRelease(userRef);
    if(groupRef) CFRelease(groupRef);
    

    return retCode;
}```
````